# How can I access the USB on my iPhone via Python / C?

Tags: iphone, python, objective-c, ios, jailbreak

I was wondering how to get access to the USB (kind of /dev/usb) on my jailbroken iPhone, 
and how could I listen what is going on ( when I plug a device on my iPhone ) for a debug purpose (because I try to create a device that I could connect directly on my iPhone).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a member of the [MFi Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) to get access to development information for iOS Accessories.

Comment: I didn't know this MFI Program, i'm gonna read this thing, thanks for the answer.  But I was also looking for informations on the tty.[USB_Device] inside the phone ( that i could access through python or what ever else language)

Comment: People that are in the MFi program likely couldn't reveal what kind of UN*X-style access is available due to NDAs.  That program costs more and has more restrictions than the normal developer program. - - - i've never delved into any of that, good luck - - - always thought it would be cool to use an iPhone/iPad as a development platform for arduino, but no can do (for free)